# How to show a Modal Dialog and Cancel Navigation in OnNavigatingFromAsync

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, template10

When using [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) you are given the opportunity to have a page's ViewModel cancel navigating away from the page by overriding the `INavigable` method `OnNavigatingFromAsync` and setting `args.Cancel` to true, like so:

```
public override Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    // some logic to determine if navigation should be canceled...
    args.Cancel = true;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This works just fine, however if I wanted to show a modal dialog to the user, (explaining why the navigation is being cancelled), I would modify the method to be:

```
public async override Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = true;
    ContentDialog dlg = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "Bad",
        Content = "no no no!",
        PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
        SecondaryButtonText = "NO"
    };
    await dlg.ShowAsync();           
}
```

This will show the dialog, however the navigation is **not** cancelled. It's like T10 is ignoring `args.Cancel = true;` being set.

Am I doing something wrong here? I just want to show the dialog and then prevent navigation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am tried your Modal on Template 10 (1.1.4) on the Hamburger Sample and it works perfectly.

For me i think your error is on the method "OnNavigatingFromAsync", it looks like it is missing "return Task.CompletedTask" at the end.

For me this code stops the app from going back when I click on the back key in the app:

```
 public override Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;

            ContentDialog dlg = new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = "Bad",
                Content = "no no no!",
                PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
                SecondaryButtonText = "NO"
            };
            dlg.ShowAsync();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I guess my mistake was also await-ing the `dlg.ShowAsync`. In another attempt I was returning the `IAwaitable` from `dlg.ShowAsync().AsTask()`  which also didn't work. I guess I don't quite understand what Task should be returned, and why returning CompletedTask works...

Comment: Hrm.. I wonder if this [commit](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/commit/62fe468655b8998495e73ae2f1c9d5b47faaba19) changes anything here? Instead of returning the `Task.CompletedTask`, Jerry now `await`s it.